# Can I grep two files against each other?

Tags: linux, grep

I want to grep file A for every phrase in file B, where a phrase is a string of words of length X. Ideally, it would be an approximate grep, like `agrep`. Is there a way to do that using command-line tools?

File A:

"Once upon a time I heard a story about bananas in space."

File B:

"If there's one thing I'm not concerned with, bananas in space is not that concern."

Output:

Phrase "bananas in space" found in File A line 1, file B line 1.

(and it might highlight the phrase in context, like grep does.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following in bash :

```
while read line  
do  
   grep "$line" fileA  
done < fileB
```

Comment: That will grep fileA for every *line* in fileB, but I'm looking for it to grep every phrase.

Comment: You mean natural language phrases ending by a punctuation ?

Comment: Any sequence of words. So in "I like to eat apples" there would be the phrases "I like," "I like to," "like to eat," "eat apples," etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you wish to do is over any command line tools, it is done by  full text search-capable programs.
Something much less is achievable using awk:

```
$ cat fts.awk
{ gsub( /[[:space:],."!?]+/, " ") }

FILENAME == "A" {
   A[++cntA] = $0
   next
}

FILENAME == "B" {
   for ( nrA=1; nrA<=cntA; ++nrA) {
      for ( first=1; first<=NF; ++first) {
         for ( last=first; last<=NF; ++last) {
            lookfor = (last == first) ? $first : lookfor " " $last
            #print "lookfor=", lookfor
            #print "<", A[nrA]
            if ( index(A[nrA], lookfor)) {
               #print "FOUND>", found, nrA, NR
               found = lookfor
            } else if (found) {
               printf "Phrase \"%s\" found in File A line %d, file B line %d.\n",\
                   found, nrA, FNR
               found = ""
               break
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Which can be called as:

```
$ awk -f fts.awk A B
Phrase "bananas in space" found in File A line 1, file B line 1.
Phrase "in space" found in File A line 1, file B line 1.
Phrase "space" found in File A line 1, file B line 1.
```

As you can see, the code is already becoming complex, although it does hardly any of your feature list, it does not even have a memory to eliminate showing subfindings.

Answer (score 0):

Lets simplify this a bit, and then build up to the soution.

You can grep a file with patterns from a file by using the -f option.  So you could do something like this.

```
grep -f file_patterns file_haystack
```

You can use process substitution to make the output of a process act like a file

```
cat <( grep pattern file )
```

If you put this together you can grep a file based on the output of a grep command like this.

```
grep -f <( grep pattern file_a ) file_b
```

I assume you can figure out the pattern bit on your own, because it isn't clear to me at all from your description, what that is supposed to be.